# Is it my Kindle appearing as VAP430 in Google Security Audit?

Tags: google-account, security, kindle

Google has a nice security feature where you can check the devices that connected via your account over the last month.  When I recently ran this report I was alarmed to see a "Vizio VAP430" appearing, a device which I do not own.  First thought was that this was an intrusion.  However after thinking about the times reported, I realized that they corresponding to when I accessed my Google account via my Kindle.

So my questions are:

1. Has anyone else seen this behavior?
2. Why would a Kindle be reported as a VAP430?

Comment: http://www.vizio.com/costar.html

Answer (score 0):

Seems that rather it's your [smart television](http://www.vizio.com/costar.html).